# What if threefold repetition occurs in WCC 2018?

Tags: draw, world-championship, threefold-repetition

It is not allowed to draw till move 30. Are the players forced to find another moves in case of threefold repetition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Draw by mutual agreement is not allowed before move 30. But a draw by threefold repetition can be claimed at any point if it occurs.

Comment: And a stale-mate would also be allowed ...

Comment: ...and the players can agree on a draw at any time if the arbiter allows it.